# What if someone curses me?

Tags: practical-islam, language, curse

What if someone curses me, like someone uses an F word on me? What should be my response to that person according to the teachings of Islam? Should I stay quiet or curse him/her back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> يقول الله تعالى: وَالَّذِين
> إِذَا أَصَابَهُمُ الْبَغْيُ هُمْ يَنْتَصِرُونَ
>
> - وَجَزَاءُ سَيِّئَةٍ سَيِّئَةٌ مِثْلُهَا فَمَنْ عَفَا وَأَصْلَحَ فَأَجْرُهُ عَلَى اللَّهِ إِنَّهُ لَا يُحِبُّ الظَّالِمِين

If a person is insulted by someone who is insulting him in the same manner as is permissible(mubah) , if he does not go beyond the oppressed,but amnesty is better

> في الحديث: المتسابان ماقالا فعلى البادئ منهما ما لم يعتد المظلوم. رواه مسلم.

if two person who insult each other will be their sin on the one who started unless the other person insulting him more and bad words he get as much as he insult the other person
but if he insult his  sibling is Haram and word that is bad and not accepted by any one Fore example F and it similarity ([Here](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/123281))

والله اعلم

Comment: What if someone abuses your parents, or your siblings? In that case is it permissible to abuse his/her parents or siblings in revenge?

Comment: @laser2302 this is not how our Prophet pbuh taught us to act.

Comment: @laser2302 if you insult his family it is Haram because " **AND NO BEARER of burdens shall be made to bear another’s burden;**  "Fatir35:18 " you should not defend about your family by insulting his family it's not their fault if he is an  idiot